# Dropdown list with foreign key

Tags: php

I have a problem concerning my drop-down list in PHP. I have in fact 2 tables.

The first is the table `feedbacks` with several fields `(id_feedback, lesson_feedback, description_feedback, fk_candidat)`

My second table is `candidats` with 3 fields `(id_candidat, name_candidat, firstname_candidat)`

When I want to add a recordery from my form `feedbacks`. 
I must to get the fields below `lesson_feedback, description_feedback, name_candidat (with a drop-down-list), firstname_candidat (with a drop-down-list)`.

My problem is I don't recover the fk_candidat for the firstname_candidat. 
I recover the fk_candidat for the name_candidat only. 
I need of the name and of the firstname.

[image]

Here is an idea of the code

```
if(isset($_POST['lesson_feedback']) AND isset($_POST['description_feedback']) AND isset($_POST['fk_candidat'])){

   $lesson_feedback = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lesson_feedback']);
   $description_feedback = htmlspecialchars($_POST['description_feedback']);
   $fk_candidat = ($_POST['fk_candidat']);

   $req_add = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO feedbacks (lesson_feedback,description_feedback, fk_candidat) VALUES (?,?,?)");

   $req_add->execute(array($lesson_feedback, $description_feedback, $fk_candidat));

}

$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM candidats");
```

In HTML

```
<form action="add_feedbacks.php" method="POST">
<table>
   <tr><td>Lesson:</td><td><input type="text" name="lesson_feedback'"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Description:</td><td><input type="text" name="description_feedback'"/ </td></tr>
   <tr><td>Name candidat:</td><td><select name="fk_candidat" style="width:148px">
   <?php

   while($row = $sql->fetch()) { 
   ?>

   <option value="<?= $row['id_candidat']; ?>"><?= $row['name_candidat'];?>    </option>

   <?php
   }
   ?>
   </select>

   <tr><td>Firstname candidat:</td><td><select name="fk_candidat" style="width:148px">
   <?php
   while($row = $sql->fetch()) { 
   ?>
   <option value="<?= $row['id_candidat']; ?>"<?= $row['firstname_candidat'];?></option>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  </select>

  <tr><td colspan="2"><input class="button" type="submit" value="Ajouter"/> 
  </td></tr>
</table>

</form>
```

I think my problem is here ?

```
<tr><td>Firstname candidat:</td><td><select name="fk_candidat" style="width:148px">
       <?php
       while($row = $sql->fetch()) { 
       ?>
       <option value="<?= $row['id_candidat']; ?>"<?= $row['firstname_candidat'];?></option>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
      </select>
```

Comment: Your problem looks like you are trying to split 1 row into 2 distinct pieces of data, (granted without the schema that's just a guess).  How to resolve that? who knows that's up to you.  For example it looks like `name_candidat`, `firstname_candidat` and `id_candidat` all belong to the same row, so saying `My problem is I don't recover the fk_candidat for the firstname_candidat.` is incorrect because you have it, it's just the same as the other name value as it's the same row.

Comment: Now as to why the first name is not populated, well you can only loop on a DB cursor 1 time (`$row = $sql->fetch()`), they cannot be rewound (which you are not doing anyway, but wouldn't work).  So by the time you get to the second `while` loop, you have all ready iterated though the result set, and as such you are at the end of the "array" and can go no more, Make sense.  You may be able to combine them in the same loop, but I think your schema will still give you issues.

Comment: If possible the best bet is to use one drop down and combine the 2 names in it `<option value="<?= $row['id_candidat']; ?>" ><?= $row['firstname_candidat'].;?>&nbsp;<?= $row['name_candidat'];?></option>`  The problem you have is you cant really treat 2 pieces of data that belong to the same row as 2 independent pieces of data, because they are not independent of each other.  Maybe there is a way it will work for you, but I think it won't be "pretty"

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: hi, thank you a lot, my problem is solve. thank you